# Magick::EnableOpenCL returns true but has no effect

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I have successfully built Imagemagick with `--enable-opencl=yes`

`magick --version` shows:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.6-10 Q16 x86_64 2020-06-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg wmf x xml zlib
```

However, this code doesn't use GPU at all despite the fact that `Magick::EnableOpenCL()` does return 1.

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Magick;

int main() {
    printf("EnableOpenCL ret: %d\n", Magick::EnableOpenCL());
    Magick::Image svgImage;
    svgImage.read("input.svg"); // first read file
    svgImage.magick("png"); // then specify PNG format
    svgImage.write("output.png");
    return 0;
}
```

I have an NVIDIA driver with cuda 10 installed. What is the problem I'm experiencing and how do I solve it? I also noticed that some people include `MagickCore/accelerate.h` and `MagickCore/accelerate-private.h` but I cannot include them because there are no such files in my header folders.

Comment: Only certain ImageMagick methods use GPU acceleration. See https://imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php Reading and writing images are generally not accelerated.

Comment: thank you @fmw42. that's the answer.